# How to search for layers in the layers panel?

Tags: qgis, layers

I have QGIS projects with a lot of layers. Sometime it's difficult to find a layer into Layers Panel. How to search it?

Comment: I don't think there's a way. I suggest you create sensible layer groups and the search will become easier.